# ARM instruction to hex for loads like pc-relative LDR

Tags: assembly, arm, machine-code, instruction-encoding, relative-addressing

I've been trying to translate the arm instruction to hex which include PC register, for example

```
ldr rx, [pc, #xx]
```

I have checked the "ARM Architecture Reference Manual", and the description of LDR instruction is as below:
[image]

Questions appeared, 
    1. the cond value, see [Instruction Format](http://www.nyx.net/~troddis/ARM.html), LDR instruction's correspond cond value is 0101(PLUS) or else? 
    2, Rd is PC register, and how to describe PC use the four bits[15:12]

Comment: ARM instructions by default are unconditional, which is `1110` (aka ALways). PC is R15, aka `1111`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm just started to learn ARM instruction, thanks for your help. BTW: the hex value of the instruction above is:1110 0101 1001 1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way to figure this out is to just write some code and disassemble, see what that particular toolchain has encoded and then compare that to the docs...

```
.globl _start
_start:

ldr r3,hello
nop
nop
nop
nop
hello: .word 0x1234
```

which gives

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 14 <hello>
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  10:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)

00000014 <hello>:
  14:   00001234    andeq   r1, r0, r4, lsr r2
```

the instruction in question

```
e59f300c
11100101100111110011000000001100
1110 01 0 1 1 0 0 1 1111 0011 000000001100
```

as mentioned the condition code is 1110 which is "ALways".  the Rn is the pc and the Rd is r3.  The pc is in bits 19:16 not 15:12.

the desired address is 0x14 in this case with the instruction at 0x00.  So for that instruction the pc is 0x08 when executing so 0x14-0x08 is 0x0C which is the offset encoded.